# Liberty 19.0.0.2 EE 6 stack SSL configuration will not work

Tags: java, ssl, java-ee-6, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to get SSL configured in liberty for jax-ws service calls.  I'm stuck in the EE 6 framework and have to get it working in this environment.  However I did try the following

EE8 stack server.xml configuration

```xml
<featureManager>
   <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
   <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
   <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
   <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
   <feature>jpa-2.2</feature>
   <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
   <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
   <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
   <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
   <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
   <feature>jaxrsClient-2.1</feature>
   <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="ibm/api">
    <user name="wasadmin" password="wasadmin" />
</basicRegistry>

<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="keystore.p12" password="mypass" type="PKCS12"/>
<keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" location="keystore.p12" password="mypass" type="PKCS12"/>

<sslDefault sslRef="myDefaultSSLConfig" />
<ssl id="myDefaultSSLConfig"
     keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
     trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore"
     clientAuthentication="true"
     sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" />
```

this setup works straight out of the box and I did not experience any difficulties.

EE6 stack server.xml configuration

```xml
<featureManager>
    <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
    <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
</featureManager>

<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="ibm/api">
    <user name="wasadmin" password="wasadmin" />
</basicRegistry>

<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="keystore.p12" password="mypass" type="PKCS12"/>
<keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" location="keystore.p12" password="mypass" type="PKCS12"/>

<sslDefault sslRef="myDefaultSSLConfig" />
<ssl id="myDefaultSSLConfig"
     keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
     trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore"
     clientAuthentication="true"
     sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" />
```

I can't get it to work with this configuration

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
```

is there any special configuration you need to apply to get it to work with an EE 6 stack ?

There is one workaround we have to get it to work but it's one we would never want to use in an UAT or PROD environment

workaround: add it to the jvm startup params

```
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\IBM\wlp\usr\servers\rekening-courant\resources\security\key.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=MyPass
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\IBM\wlp\usr\servers\rekening-courant\resources\security\trust.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=MyPass
```

## How I setup the jax-ws connection (sorry for the dutch my employer requires me to program in dutch)

creating the service endpoint connection

```
public class ServiceClientProducer {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceClientProducer.class);

    @Inject
    private SoapServiceFactory soapServiceFactory;

    @Inject
    private ConnectionManager connectionManager;

    public ServiceClientProducer() {
    }

    public IThirdPartyService produceerClient(ClientConfig config) {
        logger.debug("Produceer ServiceClient: configuratie: [{}]", config);
        ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService = soapServiceFactory.createThirdPartyService();
        IThirdPartyService connection = thirdPartyService.getBasicHttpBindingIThirdPartyService();
        connectionManager.configureerConnectie(config, (BindingProvider) connection);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

The connection manager

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    public void configureerConnectie(ClientConfig config, BindingProvider connectie) {
        Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = new HashMap<>();

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(config.getEndpoint())) {
            URL url = config.getHost();
            String endpointAddress = url.toString() + config.getEndpoint();
            connectie.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointAddress);
        }

        if (config.isSecured()) {
            connectie.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, config.getUser());
            connectie.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, config.getPassword());
        }

        if(config.hasToken()){
            requestHeaders.put("X-Auth", Arrays.asList(config.getToken()));
        }

        if(config.hasLanguage()){
            requestHeaders.put("Accept-Language", Arrays.asList(config.getLanguage().getStringValue()));
        }

        connectie.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, requestHeaders);

        Binding binding = connectie.getBinding();

        List<Handler> handlerChain = binding.getHandlerChain();
        handlerChain.add(new MessageLogger());
        binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
    }
}
```

Third party wsdl jax-ws generated method

```
/**
 *
 * @return
 *     returns IThirdPartyService
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "BasicHttpBinding_IThirdPartyService")
public IThirdPartyService getBasicHttpBindingIThirdPartyService() {
    return super.getPort(BasicHttpBindingIThirdPartyService, IThirdPartyService.class);
}
```

Putting it all together

```
public List<StationDto> getStations(GetStationsRequestDetails request) {
    logger.trace("Calling getStations: [{}]", request);
    String token = getToken(request);
    ClientConfig config = clientConfigBuilder.buildConfig(request.getEndpoint(), token, request.getConnectionLanguage());
    IThirdPartyService thirdPartyService = serviceClientProducer.produceerClient(config);
    GetStationsResponse response = thirdPartyService.getStations(serviceRequestsBuilder.buildGetStationsRequest(request));
    return stationResponseProcessor.process(response);
}
```

There are some utility classes here that do stuff that don't really relate to the problem so I omitted them from the question

Comment: That error stack you just pasted there: is it produced by a client application trying to access your server?

Comment: No it's my REST service calling a SOAP service that requires an SSL handshake

Comment: What is being used to make your outbound connection?   If your code is calling something that creates it's own SSLContext then Liberty's SSL configuration information will be bypassed.

Comment: Oh... keystore.*p12* vs key & trust.*jks*. I bet the JEE 6 stuff can't read the p12 format?

Comment: My very first attempts where with jks.  This is my later progression in trying to debug the problem where I attempted a p12 format as keystore.  I'm appending my question with the jax-ws setup for one of the soap services on how I make the outbound connection